# ScrollViewer control template breaks textboxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I copied `ScrollViewer` template from MSDN ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and it breaks textbox behavior. Scroll now doesn't follow selection when I select text using mouse. Why? How to fix it?

Here's my code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
      <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
              Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Border Grid.Column="1"
                      BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
                <Border.BorderBrush>
                  <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                </Border.BorderBrush>
                <ScrollContentPresenter />
              </Border>
              <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                         Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                         Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                         ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                         Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
              <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                         Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                         ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                         Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Margin="20"
             Width="100"
             Text="sdjkfhsdjkfhjkdshxcmvnm,xcnv,mxcnv, mxcnv,mxcngjklsdjkfh jkdfghjkfhgjkdfhgkjdfghkjdfhgbkjcvhbkcvjbh" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I use .NET 4

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I finally solved by adding CanContenScroll="True" to ScrollContentPresenter.

```
<ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" CanContentScroll="True"/>
```

and if you want to make it more flexible just bind it to ancestor value:

```
 <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                         CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I get the same behaviour. I'm afraid I can't really figure out why it's happening, it's probably a bug in WPF or in the way they've defined the control template.

The TextBox's control template has a scroll viewer as part of its layout and obviously the template is interfering with that somehow.

The only suggestion I can make is that you give your style an x:Key value and only reference that style on the ScrollViewer element in the specific cases that you need it, rather than applying it to all ScrollViewers. Then the ScrollViewer that is contained in the TextBox's element tree would not pick up on it. A bit of a pain and you lose the dynamic nature of WPF templating but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your style is targeting **ALL** controls of type `ScrollViewer` in the `Window` as the style does not have a key (`x:Key`) set - This is a problem since `TextBox` actually uses a `ScrollViewer` in its template.

Try using `<Style x:Key="MyScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">`. You can then reference this style on your `ScrollViewer` like so: `<ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource MyScrollViewerStyle}">`